# How to Load a Fixed Width Table of Digits with No Delimiter into Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

This is how the table file looks like (but much larger):

```
   058375
   758364
   000100
```

Each digit is a value. For example, the first row has the values:

```
[0, 5, 8, 3, 7, 5]
```

I don't know the number of columns and the number of rows in each file ahead of time.

Comment: show your efforts and post the expected dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a "pandonic" way of doing it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data", header = None, dtype = "str")
df = df.apply(lambda series : [ char for char in series[0] ], axis = 1, result_type = "expand")

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  5  8  3  7  5
1  7  5  8  3  6  4
2  0  0  0  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "pythonic" way of doing it:

```
import pandas as pd

with open("data") as file:
    df = pd.DataFrame([ [ char for char in line.rstrip() ] for line in file ])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  5  8  3  7  5
1  7  5  8  3  6  4
2  0  0  0  1  0  0
```